# Script can't write to systemd journal

Tags: bash, scripting, systemd, systemd-journald

To make it short: I want to write to the `systemd` journal from a script.

This doesn't work:

```shell
printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n" CODE_FILE=/etc/zsh/zprofile CODE_LINE=31 MESSAGE="could not read /etc/dircolors" | logger --journald
```

When I execute that exact code (or any other variant with print, etc.), nothing happens in the journal.

I call `journalctl` like this:

```
journalctl --full --all --no-pager -n 10
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: try `journalctl SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=logger` as `root`.

Comment: Works for me :-). Please post the version numbers of systemd, and `logger`, including where you installed them from in case there are any custom patches.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`systemd-cat`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-cat.html). It connects a pipeline or program output with the journal.

Example:

```
printf "Write text to the journal" | systemd-cat
```

Result:

```
journalctl -xn
[..]
Apr 12 13:37:00 servername [31509]: Write text to the journal
```

If you want to identify the logging tool you can add the [*-t*](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-cat.html#-t) option:

```
printf "Write text to the journal" | systemd-cat -t yourIdentifier
journalctl -xn
Apr 12 13:37:00 servername yourIdentifier[31833]: Write text to the journal
```

Edit:
To show messages for the specified syslog identifier only, use the -t option:

```
journalctl -t yourIdentifier
```

This parameter can be specified multiple times.

Comment: Is there a way to make all stdout and stderr directed to journal from within the script instead of just specific commands?

Answer (score 2):

`| systemd-cat` won't work if:

- the script is being executed directly by systemd, and
- the script has redirected stdout/stderr (`exec 1>>$LOGFILE`)

This is still true even if you `| tee systemd-cat`.

In this case the best action is to reverse it:

- remove the redirect of stdout
- make your `printf` calls perform the `| tee -a $LOGFILE`

Comment: Welcome to posting on Unix StackExchange :-). This is very interesting, but it is not an answer to the question, which uses `logger` only. A short pointer to this information might have been useful as a comment on the other answer - the site will [let you post comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) when you have made "enough" other contributions). There are two alternatives. One, you could flesh this answer out to explicitly say that `| systemd-cat` is an alternative that you think would be more reliable.

Comment: Two, you can post a new question+answer on this specific topic, using the question to illustrate the case(s) where `| systemd-cat` doesn't work, and providing this explanation as an answer.  Self-answers to valid questions are allowed and encouraged :-).

Comment: Personally I would not upvote option one, for the same reason I have not upvoted the answer by xloto. Other people have found that useful though, so if this is what you think then I would feel free to do so! I would be willing to upvote option two if I saw it though.